# Do something when a AJAX load has completed successfully

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am totally gutted, I just lost a whole load of code and trying in a rush to get it sorted. I have got most done but I have a section that when a button is clicked it loads a page and displays it with AJAX. All works fine but I want to add a loading gif when it starts and then hide it only when its complete. I keep getting errors and I know its easily possible but keep getting it wrong.

I have just added this to end, is it correct? It says it checks for all completed AJAX functions?

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  //alert("LOADED");
  $('#loader').hide();
});
```

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainstuff button").click(function(){
    $('#loader').show();
        status = $(this).attr("data-name");
        var new_url = "demo_text.php?job_id="+status;
        //alert(status);
        $("#div1").load(new_url);

// I want to hide when its loaded successfully here 
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
});
```

I know its something like

```
.load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
```

But I keep getting errors, any help would be great thanks

Comment: Mentioning the errors here would be a good start. ;)

Comment: Put this into a codepen/jsfiddle. Please post the exact errors you are seeing.

Comment: @ChrisCousins - if you click the edit, there is an icon to basically create a fiddle in line in the question.  But you probably knew that

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss there isn't enough complete code in here to do that; it is incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `load` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/), you would do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainstuff button").click(function(){
    $('#loader').show();
        status = $(this).attr("data-name");
        var new_url = "demo_text.php?job_id="+status;
        $("#div1").load(new_url, function() {
            // Callback executed once the load has been performed
            $('#loader').hide();
        });        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways, but to give yourself flexibility you might consider the promises way (second one).

I also adjusted some of your other code, removed globals, used `.data()` instead of the `attr()` etc.

Note you COULD use the ajax events like ajaxStop, I put an example of that in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mainstuff").on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('#loader').show();
    let status = $(this).data("name");
    let new_url = "demo_text.php?job_id=" + status;
    $("#div1").load(new_url, function(newcontent) {
      $('#loader').hide();
      $(this).html(newcontent);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second way using promises: note remove those you do not desire.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("ajaxSend", function() {
    $("#loading").show();
  }).on("ajaxStop", function() {
    $("#loading").hide(1000);
  });

  $(".mainstuff").on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('#loader').show();
    let status = $(this).data("name");
    let new_url = "demo_text.php?job_id=" + status;

    var myloader = $.ajax({
      url: new_url,
      data: {},
      dataType: "html", // or whatever returns
      type: 'GET'
    });
    myloader.done(function(newcontent) {
      $("#div1").html(newcontent);
    });
    // hide in second "success", could be in prior
    myloader.done(function(newcontent, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#loader').hide();
    });
    // process when we fail!
    myloader.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#loader').hide();
      $('#loadfailed').text(textStatus+ " We are sorry, something is not right").show();
    });
    // hide no matter what when ajax returns
    myloader.always(function(newcontent) {
      $('#loader').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader" class="hidden">Loading of Great Stuff!</div>
<div id="loading" class="hidden">Loading Great Stuff!</div>
<div id="loadfailed" class="hidden">Loading Failed</div>
<div class="mainstuff">
  <button class="mybutton" data-name="myname">Main Stuff stuffer</button>
  <div class="div1 content-holder">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".hotengine-widget-slide-menu-button", function(e){
        var we = $(this);
         if(typeof $hotengine_slide_widget == "undefined"){
           $.ajax({url: "/file.js", dataType: "script", cache: true})
           .done(function(){
             we.click();
           });
           
         }
    });
});
```

file.js - `window.$hotengine_slide_widget=1;
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on("click",".hotengine-widget-slide-menu-button", function(e){ other fucntion`

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do after Ajax success

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    type: 'POST',//'GET','PUT','DELETE'
    headers: headers,
    data: {
        "fname": $("#fname").val(),
        "lname": $("#lname").val(),
        "email": $("#email").val()
    }
})
.then( result => {
    //append result to your html
    //Dynamic view
    $("#form1").hide();
    var html = '<div><span>First Name: ' + result.fName + '</span><span>Last Name: ' + result.lName + '</span></div>';
    $("#showValue").html(html);    
})
.catch( error => {
    alert('error ',error);
});
```

Comment: the OP is using the `.load` method and it will work perfectly for his case as it accepts a callback function to be executed when the `AJAX` call is finished, in that callback you can check the status and do whatever you want to do if the `AJAX` has succeeded/failed.